# Nested promises in ui-router resolve

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, promise, resolve

I would like to get some data before the view shows, (resolve). But some of the data is dependent on the result of another promise. I get the job id (index) from `$stateParams` and look up the data in my service. Once completed, from this result (the job) I look up the settings and floors (each from a different service). Both return a promise.

I've came up with:

```
jobinfo: function(Jobs, Floor, JobSetting, $stateParams, $q) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

        Jobs.getByIndex($stateParams.index)
        .then(function(job) {
            console.log('got jobs');
            $q.all({floors: Floor.getByJob(job), settings: JobSetting.getByJob(job)})
            .then(function(info) {
                console.log('got info');
                defer.resolve([job, info.floors, info.settings]);
            });
        });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

Take 2:

```
jobinfo: function(Jobs, Floor, JobSetting, $stateParams, $q) {

    return Jobs.getByIndex($stateParams.index)
        .then(function(job) {
            console.log('got jobs');
            return $q.all({floors: Floor.getByJob(job), settings: JobSetting.getByJob(job)})
            .then(function(info) {
                console.log('got info');
                return [job, info.floors, info.settings];
            });
        });
}
```

Both fail. I do not even get a `console.log` back. I left the rest of the code out, obviously they are wrapped in :

```
resolve: {
...
}
```

and defined in the right place.

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or Plunkr? Also, if you add the 'jobinfo' dependency in your controller, do you get a result? You can also check the Network tab to see if the resolve call was made

Comment: I do not get into the controller, jobinfo is set as a dependency but the controller never gets loaded. Will see if i can put this in a fiddle

Comment: Is this resolve part of an abstract state by any chance?

Comment: Yes, i have a state('app') which is abstract, and this one is state('app.plan')

Comment: You may need to inject the resolve similar to @avcajaraville answer, except into any child states that need the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to separate the resolvers.

You can inject the value on each resolver this way:

```
job : function( Jobs, $stateParams, $q ) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Jobs.getByIndex( $stateParams.index, function( job ) {
        defer.resolve( job );
    });
    return defer.promise;
},

floor : function( Floor, job, $q ) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Floor.getByJob( job, function( floor ) {
        defer.resolve( floor );
    });
    return defer.promise;
},

settings : function( JobSetting, job, $q ) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    JobSetting.getByJob( job, function( settings ) {
        defer.resolve( settings );
    });
    return defer.promise;
},
```

From [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains
>   key/value pairs of
>
> - key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
> - factory - {string|function}:
>
> [...]
>
> if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as
>   the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the
>   controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the
>   controller.

Comment: I think the "strange" behavior might be related to the fact that I suppose you were using ngResource. Are you using it ?

Comment: I am using ui-router, Altho this state is part of an abstract state and I am also using ionic. Maybe one of those give me this strange behaviour.

Comment: $q and other 'outer' injectables must be placed in first places. 
use 'settings : function(  $q, JobSetting, job )'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jobinfo: function(Jobs, Floor, JobSetting, $stateParams, $q) {

              var defer = $q.defer();

              Jobs.getByIndex($stateParams.index)
                  .then(function(job) {
                      console.log('got jobs');
                      var floors = Floor.getByJob(job);
                      var settings = JobSetting.getByJob(job);
                      $q.all([floors, settings])
                      .then(function(info) {
                          console.log('got info');
                          defer.resolve([job, info[0], info[1]]);
                      });
                  });

              return defer.promise;
          }
```

Comment: `$q.all` can take an array or an object, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

Comment: I tried it out and i get the same result, no logs and view does not get shown.

Comment: did you get console.log('got jobs'); log?