# Angular UI-Router state resolve depending on another resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**EDIT:** this actually works, the problem was coming from something else.

I am struggling with an edge-case scenario, basically:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  resolve:{
    resolveA:  function($q){
      return $q.when('whatever');
    },
    resolveB:  function(resolveA){
      return fetchSomethingBasedOn(resolveA);
    }
  }
);
```

This does not work as `resolveA` can't be injected in `resolveB` function.

There are a few options I already considered but rejected:

1. Make the resolveA returned value an object `{resolveA, resolveB}`. Discarded because this would have many side effects on my existing controllers.
2. Handle the resolveB behaviour at the `controller` level. Discarded because this state is an abstract high level one, I don't wan't to change all its children `states/controllers`

Comment: Actually, this should work. You can do what you are trying, you have to be sure that your resolveA is returning a promise.

Comment: I tried that and never managed to have it work. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895140/nested-promises-in-ui-router-resolve/30895530#30895530

Comment: Well that's weird. I'll keep trying then.

Comment: Probably you are not returning a promise on resolveA

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying to inject a service with a misspelled name... Shame on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ui-router nested resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states) doesn't work on the same state, but it should work on nested states. You can access `resolved` objects from the parent state.

```
$stateProvider
.state('parent', {
  resolve:{
    resolveA:  function($q){
      return $q.when('whatever');
    }
  }
)
.state('parent.child', {
  resolve:{
    resolveB:  function(resolveA){
      return fetchSomethingBasedOn(resolveA);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The option that seems OK-ish is to attach the result of resolveB to the resolveA object and have only one resolve. i.e:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  resolve:{
    resolveA:  function($q){
      return $q.when('whatever').then(function(resolveA){
        return fetchSomethingBasedOnResolveA(resolveA).then(function(resolveB){
           resolveA.resolveB = resolveB;
           return resolveA;
        })
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem is by using promises. You must be sure that the promise for resolveA is resolved before start with resolveB.

The code should be something like this.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
resolve:{
resolveA:  function($q){
  var def = $q.defer();
//whatever you want i.e.
  User.resource.get(function(perfil){
          def.resolve(perfil);
        });
//
  return def.promise;

},
resolveB:  function(resolveA){
  return fetchSomethingBasedOn(resolveA);
}});
```

And this should solve your problems.

Greetings.